# popup menu in eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to create plugin in which if user right click on any folder or file, the popup menu will open and there is option to read file.
As I am new to plugin development have done some code. My plugin.xml is following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            name="Sample Category"
            id="com_.samsung.plugin.second.commands.category">
      </category>
      <command
            name="Sample Command"
            categoryId="com_.samsung.plugin.second.commands.category"
            id="com_.samsung.plugin.second.commands.sampleCommand">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com .samsung.plugin.second.SampleHandler"
            id="com .samsung.plugin.second.Sample"
            name="name">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            commandId="com_.samsung.plugin.second.commands.sampleCommand"
            class="com_.samsung.plugin.second.handlers.SampleHandler">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="com_.samsung.plugin.second.commands.sampleCommand"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            sequence="M1+6"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
         <command commandId="com_.samsung.plugin.second"
            label="Read File" style="push">
        </command>
      </menuContribution>

   </extension>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command defaultHandler="com_.samsung.plugin.second.handler.SampleHandler"
      id="com_.samsung.plugin.second" name="Convert">
    </command>
  </extension>

</plugin>
```

and i have a **SampleHandler** class in **com_.samsung.plugin.second.handlers;**

but in popup Readfile option is not visible.

please suggest me whats wrong with this.

any help will be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: You must add `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` to `extension`.